# Translation Help - Is "Semper veritate amemus" correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm wanting a Latin translation for "May we always find love in what is true" or as a reduced version "May we always love in truth". I'm wanting this as an inscription on a ring so it needs to fit into 30 characters (pref 25).

Is this as simple as *"Semper veritate amemus"* ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it gets the point across well enough, but it means more "Let us always love with/by means of truth." For "in truth", you'll want to add *in*.

Thinking about it, too, I'm not quite sure what "may we always love in truth" *really* means in English. It seems straightforward upon first reading, but the "in truth" is actually not clear at all. Inside truth? In reality (i.e. contradicting a mistaken assumption)? It certainly doesn't mean the same thing as "May we always find love in what is true." But I think for the longer quote, you have a few options, which keep it brief..

If you're open to > 25 characters, might I suggest:

> Vera amorem nostram semper ducant?
> May the truth always lead our love.

Alternatively, you could personify truth more:

> Veritate duce semper amantes
> Always loving, with truth as our guide

That one has exactly 25 characters to it, too. The form, *amantes*, is a participle (which can be used absolutely) modifying a plural noun. While *we* isn't necessarily implied, that's more just dependent on context. Moreover, these are a little more clearly defined than *semper in veritate amemus*.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much for your help - that is really really great. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Kim Happy to help. Once you've chosen a translation, remember to click the check mark, which will mark it solved.

Answer (score 4):

As @cmw says, it does depend what you mean in English. Half the trouble in translating from a soft language like English to a hard language like Latin is deciding what the soft language is actually saying.

“In truth” could mean something as weak as “truly”, in which case *vere* would do it.

You are likelier to be referring not to whether you are loving truly or falsely but what kind of mode of loving is in question (attraction, convenience, fantasy, reality, truth). You can diagnose that this is your meaning by asking yourself if you could pronounce it as “love — in — truth” with breath pauses as shown.

If you can, then the Vulgate will help you:

John 4:24 - *spiritus est Deus et eos qui adorant eum in spiritu et veritate oportet adorare*

and this will imply “in veritate” in place of your “veritate”

I would also put in a word for a change in word order. This is much more a matter of taste and ear and so others may want to jump in; but in general putting something at the end gives it emphasis as being the final piece of the story. You miss an opportunity by putting “amemus” in that position.

Here are two choices.

*Semper amemus in veritate* “Let us always love” - “In what way?” - “In truth”.

*Amemus in veritate semper* - “Let us love” - “In what way?” - “In truth” - “How long should we love in this particular way as opposed to some other way?” - “Always”.